# Print JSON response in Java when using REST API & HttpClient

Tags: java, json, rest

I want to know if there is an error response when sending the REST POST request, and i want to print the error as "output" in my Java application.

How do i do this?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("example.com/api/deposit");
    StringEntity params;
    params = new StringEntity("{"
    + "\"locale\": \"" + exampleclass.getLocale() + "\","
    + "\"dateFormat\": \"" + exampleclass.getDateFormat() + "\","
    + "\"transactionDate\": \"" + exampleclass.getTransactionDate() + "\","
    + "\"transactionAmount\": \"" + exampleclass.getTransactionAmount() + "\","
    + "}");
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic somecode&&!!");
    request.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    //handle the response somehow
    //example : System.out.println (errormessage);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    ex.getMessage();
    } finally {
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to read the returned HTTP status code in the HttpResponse response.

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

return the HTTP code, 200 means OK, another code indicate error.

Comment: I don't see anything in my output window except " build successful ", I want to see the HTTP status code as you mentioned + the reason why, for example " account with identifier 15 does not exist ".

Comment: You can debug your code to inspect returned value at runtime, error code have associated reason defined see [rfc2616] (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html), any other information provided is specific for the server, see eventual documentation for the web service

Comment: Thank you for this line of code, it was helpful eventhough it wasn't entirely what I was looking for, upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use something as below:-

```
    String line = null;
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```